# How write a rule to exit program in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I want to write a rule to exit prolog but how can I do this?
What should I do so that I can exit the program? 
I tried something like this 
`do(exit):-halt`, but `halt` does not work.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want to use this?

Comment: halt works: `g(X) :- a(X), halt.`
?- g(X).
% exits from swipl

Comment: Could you give more details about your issue?

Comment: halt works but it exit the prolog. I just I want exit the program but stay in the prolog terminal.

Comment: try abort. It may work

Comment: Or break: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=break/0

Answer (score 1):

try and use halt(0). this also finishes swi-pl.